# Data Transfer without Transceiver on FPGA

Tags: fpga, transceiver

While going through the transceiver component on an FPGA, I realized that data transfer can take place without transceivers as well, although the speed would reduce or in other words, as tasks increase a speed cap would be reached. 
My question is: how can data transfer take place if we do not have transceivers on an FPGA? What is that mechanism?

Comment: The whole point of an FPGA is you can configure it to implement whatever protocol you want assuming you have enough pins, logic cells, and the ability to meet timing constraints. If you want to implement a UART or SPI, there's tons of code available that will do it. If you want to create a custom protocol, that's also completely doable. At high speeds though, transceivers become necessary because the programmable logic doesn't operate as fast as "hard" logic (i.e. non-reconfigurable). That being said, transceivers parallelize the data so you can still implement custom protocols using them.

Comment: UART, SPI, I2C, I2S are all well known protocols which do not need an analogue transceiver.

Comment: @Oldfart, I wasn't trying to imply transceivers were needed for those. Just trying to answer "How can data transfer take place if we do not have transceivers," with a follow up bit about when transceivers are needed (i.e. high multi-gigabit rates).

Answer (score 1):

A transciever can have dedicated high speed I/Os and also dedicated MAC layers for specific interfaces. These will make your design simpler since you can directly hook-up the MAC layers for performing all the interface related tasks. If you don't use the transceiver, you may have to use soft MAC blocks (which may be present as add-on blocks in the dev environment or you may have to code the logic for these blocks) and/or other I/O pins of the FPGA.

The speed of transmission depends on different factors. The first factor would be the availability of pins that meets the timing requirements for the interface that you are designing the transceiver. In the case of high speed interfaces (PCIe, HDMI), you should have pins that are capable of handling the required switching speeds which can be connected to your custom blocks.

The second factor would be the maximum clock frequency supported by FPGA logic. For e.g. there might be dedicated hardware transceiver blocks inside the FPGA that work at a much higher clock frequency than the max FPGA logic clock frequency. In that case, your custom transceiver block cannot operate at those frequencies.

The third would be unescessary area utilisation taken up by your custom logic, which will increase the percentage of logic utilisation which may cause timing issues at higher frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is, what is the alternative to using the FPGA's on-chip serdes blocks for I/O.

The answer is, most anything you want, provided you have enough pins available and can toggle them fast enough.

If your platform uses AXI, it's possible to bridge between FPGAs using that standard, either as a pair of streams or as a multiplexed payload with full address. Xilinx has library IP for this.

If your intention is to use an external PHY, or no PHY at all, PCIe, SATA and USB SuperSpeed interfaces use a parallel I/O called **PIPE** to connect to the serdes. This is used for example in ASIC prototyping to connect an external PHY chip with an IP vendor's controller block, in order to validate that they play well together. PIPE is typically 32 bits at up to 250MHz - a demanding I/O, but it can be done.

More about PIPE here: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/phy-interface-pci-express-sata-usb30-architectures-3.1.pdf

It's also possible to support LVDS protocols using the LVDS I/O standard plus local shift registers adjacent to the pads. This technique can support MIPI CSI and DSI directly for example, or can be used to connect to a TFT LCD.

For uses like this, as well as other custom interfaces, Xilinx and Altera have defined a mezzanine header that brings out FPGA signals to daughtercards that simplify adapting FPGA digital I/O to another purpose. It's called FMC, and there's a large ecosystem of cards that support it. Think of FMC as an Arduino shield on steroids that can do a large number of I/O (up to 400) on a single, compact connector with good signal integrity.

More about FMC here: http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2011/06/fpga-mezzanine-card-fmc-game-changer.html

That said, there is a literal FPGA-centric 'shield' approach that's supported by the cheaper, smaller FPGAs. A couple of popular ones:

- Digilent 'Arty' https://store.digilentinc.com/arty
- Xilinx 'Pynq' https://store.digilentinc.com/pynq-z1-python-productivity-for-zynq-7000-arm-fpga-soc/

And here's an Arduino form factor board that has an FPGA on it: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/MKRVidor4000